# Exponente Recursivo Fallando

Tags: c++, recursión

Estaba practicando para poder hacer un exponente recursivo, y funciona pero no con `doubles` y `floats`, hago debugging y me salen warnings en la implementacion del C++. Es un seguimiento muy largo pero al final me bota el siguiente output. `-1.#IND` y si le pongo el return ternario sale:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl expo<double>(double,double)" (??$expo@N@@YANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "float __cdecl expo<float>(float,float)" (??$expo@M@@YAMMM@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename TIPO>
TIPO expo (TIPO base, TIPO veces, TIPO cont = 1)
{
    cont *= base;
    if (veces < 0) return cont;
    expo(base, 1 - veces, cont);
    //lo mismo como operador ternario
    //return (veces > 0) ? expo(base, --veces, cont * base) : cont;
}
int main()
{
    float r = expo<float>(4.0,2.0);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alguien podria decirme en que esta fallando mi codigo? Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Te he cambiado las etiquetas. Espero que no te moleste.

Comment: Y cómo esperas tratar los exponentes con decimales?? ¿Es necesario que el exponente sea decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu función es *curiosa*; con un aviso:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Indicando que no retornas nada. Y eso que haces:

```
1 - veces
```

¿ no será al revés ?

```
template< typename T > T expo( T base, T ex, T acu = 1 ) {
  return ex > 0 ? expo( base, ex - 1, acu * base ) : acu;
}
```

Y, para los números `float`, se usa el indicador `f`. En otro caso, los toma como `double`.

```
float r = expo( 4.0f, 2.0f );
```

Y un último apunte: trabajando con números en coma flotante, el resultado es *impreciso*; una función recursiva que va acumulando imprecisiones ... pues igual el resultado no se parece mucho a lo que esperas :-)

Comment: si hace `expo<float>(3.0)` el compilador solo mostraría error si no fuese capaz de convertir de `double` a `float`. Estás indicando explícitamente cual es la especialización del template

Comment: @eferion Me correcto indicar lo del sufijo para los `float`. Es mi costumbre personal. Me pasa igual con `++`. Siempre uso el pre-incremento ;-)

Comment: a mi también me pasa 

Comment: Hola @Trauma de nuevo nos encontramos por aca :D el motivo por el que puse `1 - veces` es porque si es que quisiera multiplicarlo por 0.5 no se convierta en un negativo. He probado lo que dices y ahora me sale otro error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl expo<double>(double,double)" (??$expo@N@@YANNN@Z) referenced in function _main` alguna  idea de como arreglarlo?

Comment: No comprendo porque sucede esto, si me pudieras explicar como maneja C++ esto a un nivel detallado seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: el error era que estaba definiendo el template en el header, y su implementacion la hacia en el cpp para luego llamar en el main, cuando solo tenia q implementarlo en el mismo header.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero raro de tu función es que estás usando exponentes decimales y no has previsto nada para calcular el resultado en el caso de que el número tenga decimales. Así pues el exponente debería ser entero.

Por otro lado deberías tener en cuenta que `x^0=1` y ya quedaría a tu criterio si tratar o no los exponentes negativos... en este caso vamos a asumir que no son válidos:

```
template<typename Type>
Type expo(Type base, unsigned int exponente)
{
  if( exponente == 0 )
    return 1;
  else
    return base * expo(base,exponente-1);
}
```

Al usar esta función con `float` o `double` puedes sufrir penalizaciones de precisión y esto es debido a que `float` tiene (típicamente) 6 dígitos representativos (el resto son basura) y `double` unos 12.